# Elasticsearch : Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters index : not_analyzed

Tags: elasticsearch, mapping

Hi all I am trying to create schema Test.

```
PUT /test
{
    "mappings": {
        "field1": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "field2": {  
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "field3": {
            "type": "string",
            "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "field4": {
            "type": "string",
            "analyzer": "autocomplete",
            "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        bla
        bla
        bla
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [{
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters: [index : not_analyzed] [type : string]"
        }],
        "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [featured]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [index : not_analyzed] [type : string]",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
            "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [index : not_analyzed] [type : string]"
        }
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

Please help me to resolve this error

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You're almost here, you're just missing a few things:

```
PUT /test
{
  "mappings": {
    "type_name": {                <--- add the type name
      "properties": {             <--- enclose all field definitions in "properties"
        "field1": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "field4,": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
     ...
  }
}
```

**UPDATE**

If your index already exists, you can also modify your mappings like this:

```
PUT test/_mapping/type_name
{
    "properties": {             <--- enclose all field definitions in "properties"
        "field1": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "field2": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "field3": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "field4,": {
          "type": "string",
          "analyzer": "autocomplete",
          "search_analyzer": "standard"
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**:

As of ES 7, mapping types have been removed. You can read more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

Comment: Thanks . Is it possible to create a mapping without typename . I want to insert data without typename Something like {field1,field2 ....} And not like typeName{field1,field2 ...}

Comment: Okay here What is test and what is type_name?

Comment: `test` is your index name and `type_name` is the name of your mapping type.

Comment: what is the syntax for 5.6 if you have parent-child, the docs have example but it fails for me

Comment: @KalpeshSoni feel free to ask another question with specific details to your case

Comment: copy pasted this code. it gives error: "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason": "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [type_name : {properties={field1={type=integer}, field4,={search_analyzer=standard, analyzer=autocomplete, type=string}, field3={index=not_analyzed, type=string}, field2={type=integer}}}]"

Comment: All I was missing was the ` "type_name": {`. Thanks!

Comment: For me, the `type_name` is not working. I'm using the elasticsearch-oss:7.20 docker image

Answer (score 25):

I hope the above answer works for elastic search <7.0 but in 7.0 we cannot specify doc type and it is no longer supported. And in that case if we specify doc type we get similar error.

I you are making use of Elastic search 7.0 and Nest C# lastest version(6.6). There are some breaking changes with ES 7.0 which is causing this issue. This is because we cannot specify doc type and in the version 6.6 of NEST they are using doctype. So in order to solve that untill NEST 7.0 is released, we need to download their beta package

Please go through this link for fixing it

https://xyzcoder.github.io/elasticsearch/nest/2019/04/12/es-70-and-nest-mapping-error.html

**EDIT:** NEST 7.0 is now released. NEST 7.0 works with Elastic 7.0. See the [release notes here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/releases/tag/7.0.0) for details.

Answer (score 11):

Check your Elastic version.

I had these problem because I was looking at the incorrect version's documentation.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

As of ES 7, mapping types have been removed. You can read more details [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/removal-of-types.html)

If you are using Ruby On Rails this means that you may need to remove `document_type` from your model or concern.

As an alternative to mapping types one solution is to use an index per document type.

Before:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
    index_name [Rails.env, Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.underscore].join('_')
    document_type self.name.downcase
  end
end
```

After:

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    include Elasticsearch::Model
    include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks
    index_name [Rails.env, Rails.application.class.module_parent_name.underscore, self.name.downcase].join('_')
  end
end
```

Comment: Exactly my issue! Glad it was an easy fix after spending 2 hours reading docs over this.

Answer (score 10):

I am running Elastic Search version 7.12

When I run the following command

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies?pretty -d '
{
    "mappings" : {
        "movie": {
            "properties" : {
                "year" : { "type": "date" }
            }
        }
    }   
}'
```

the following error is returned.

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
        "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [movie : {properties={year={type=date}}}]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to parse mapping [_doc]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [movie : {properties={year={type=date}}}]",
    "caused_by" : {
      "type" : "mapper_parsing_exception",
      "reason" : "Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [movie : {properties={year={type=date}}}]"
    }
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

To mitigate that, modify the json in the query as follows.

```
curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -XPUT 127.0.0.1:9200/movies?pretty -d '
{
    "mappings" : {
        "properties" : {
            "year" : { "type": "date" }
        }
    }   
}'
```

Note: Removed the "movie":{} layer. Now it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
PUT /testIndex
{
    "mappings": {
        "properties": {     <--ADD THIS
            "field1": {
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "field2": {  
                "type": "integer"
            },
            "field3": {
                "type": "string",
                "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "field4": {
                "type": "string",
                "analyzer": "autocomplete",
                "search_analyzer": "standard"
            }
        }
    },
    "settings": {
        bla
        bla
        bla
    }
}
```

Here's a similar command I know works:

```
curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Basic cGC3COJ1c2Vy925hZGFJbXBvcnABCnRl" -X PUT -d '{"mappings":{"properties":{"city":{"type": "text"}}}}' https://35.80.2.21/manzanaIndex
```

The breakdown for the above curl command is:

```
PUT /manzanaIndex
{
    "mappings":{
        "properties":{
                "city":{
                    "type": "text"
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `elasticsearch_dsl` in Python, this error might just mean that you are not using the correct version of the library.

The library version corresponds to the Elasticsearch version.

So if you are using Elasticsearch `7.x`, elasticsearch_dsl should be `7.x` and so on

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `Python`, you can also use `requests` lib:

POST_URL = '<kibana_instance>/index_name/type_name/'

postdata = 'content_in_json_file.json'

```
response = requests.request("POST", POST_URL, data=postdata, headers={'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream'})
```

Check the status and the return to see if everything went fine:

```
response.status_code

response.content
```