# Mapping index Elasticsearch timestamp custom

Tags: curl, elasticsearch

I have problem with the uploading of index in Elasticsearch.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT http://localhost:9200/technogym_error_timeline -d "{\"mappings\":{\"timestamp\":{\"type\":\"date\",\"format\":\"yyyy-MM-dd\"}}}"
```

I get this error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [format : yyyy-MM-dd] [type : date]"}],"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Failed to parse mapping [timestamp]: Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [format : yyyy-MM-dd] [type : date]","caused_by":{"type":"mapper_parsing_exception","reason":"Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters:  [format : yyyy-MM-dd] [type : date]"}},"status":400}
```

Why is my curl command wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Elasticsearch : Root mapping definition has unsupported parameters index : not\_analyzed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288997/elasticsearch-root-mapping-definition-has-unsupported-parameters-index-not-a)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the type declaration:

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT http://localhost:9200/technogym_error_timeline -d '{
   "mappings":{
     "your_type_name": {                <--- add this
         "properties": {                <--- and this
            "timestamp":{
              "type":"date",
              "format":"yyyy-MM-dd"
            }
         }
      }        
   }
}'
```

Comment: You are right. Indeed I have corrected it in :curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -XPUT http://localhost:9200/technogym_error_timeline -d "{\"mappings\": {\"_default_\":{\"properties\":{\"timestamp\":{\"type\":\"date\",\"format\":\"yyyy-MM-dd\"}}}}}". Thanks