# Elasticsearch mapping problems error

Tags: json, elasticsearch, mapping

Here's [a link](https://gist.github.com/ekstrah/57eda2421197ee9976c6a18d064c2bb1) to my gist code that I have coded and there is a screenshot of terminal which shows what kind of error it is.

I have double checked the format of JSON file but continuously getting the same error.

Please help.
Sincerely,

Comment: Is it a problem similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39288997/elasticsearch-root-mapping-definition-has-unsupported-parameters-index-not-a ?

Answer (score 0):

Update your `vuln_ip.json` to this:

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "vulnerabilities": {
      "properties": {
        "address": {
          "type": "ip"
        },
        "cpes": {
          "type": "text"
        },
        "port": {
          "type": "nested",
          "properties": {
            "portid": {
              "type": "integer"
            },
            "protocol": {
              "type": "text"
            },
            "service": {
              "type": "nested",
              "properties": {
                "extrainfo": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "name": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "ostype": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "product": {
                  "type": "text"
                },
                "version": {
                  "type": "text"
                }
              }
            },
            "state": {
              "type": "text"
            }
          }
        },
        "score": {
          "type": "text"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Modify your curl command to this `curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/vulnerable/' -d @vuln_ip.json`.