# Getting timestamp from WAF/Kinesis to Elasticsearch

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, amazon-kinesis-firehose, amazon-waf

We're trying to find how to convert the timestamp coming from AWS WAF/Kinesis Firehose into Elasticsearch so that it's type is a date field.  When the index mapping gets created it has the timestamp field but it's a type `long`, even though there seems to be an option for type `epoch_millis` (which is what the data is).

The Kibana interface says using the mapping api to change the field type but I can't seem to figure this out.  The example [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#_field_datatypes) shows how to do this with creating new indexes but kinesis is creating/rotating the indexes so we seem to need a way to modify the default.

The field looks like this

```
  "timestamp": {
    "type": "long"
  },
```

and the full index definition looks like this but again these get created on a regular basis so we are trying to figure out how to change the default

```
  "waf-prod-2018-10-05": {
    "mappings": {
      "waf-prod": {
        "properties": {
          "action": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "formatVersion": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "httpRequest": {
            "properties": {
              "args": { 
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "clientIp": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "country": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "headers": {
                "properties": {
                  "name": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  },
                  "value": {
                    "type": "text",
                    "fields": {
                      "keyword": {
                        "type": "keyword",
                        "ignore_above": 256
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              },
              "httpMethod": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "httpVersion": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "uri": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "httpSourceId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "httpSourceName": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "nonTerminatingMatchingRules": {
            "properties": {
              "action": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "ruleId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "rateBasedRuleList": {
            "properties": {
              "limitKey": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "maxRateAllowed": {
                "type": "long"
              },
              "rateBasedRuleId": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "terminatingRuleId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "terminatingRuleType": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "timestamp": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "webaclId": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

The code of the template depends of your ES version.
If you are using version **7.x**. **You need to remove** the field (the **mapping type** field, in your case called by "waf-prod") **before the properties and after the mappings**. You can try to do this (for example, this is my configuration of ES 7.x):

```
PUT _template/template_waf-logs
{
  "order": 0,
  "index_patterns": [
    "aws-waf-logs-detected-requests-*"
  ],
  "settings": {
    "index": {
      "number_of_shards": "1",
      "number_of_replicas": "0",
      "refresh_interval": "5s"
    }
  },
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "httpRequest": {
        "properties": {
          "clientIp": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "ip"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "timestamp": {
        "type": "date",
        "format": "epoch_millis"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

1. Check de documentation of AWS here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-analyze-aws-waf-logs-using-amazon-elasticsearch-service/
2. Update your knowledge with the answer of the ES community here: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/root-mapping-definition-has-unsupported-parameters-when-creating-custom-index/240690

- Explanation to **add the mapping type**: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/common-error-root-mapping-definition-has-unsupported-parameters/63300/2
- Explained by ES version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39290979/10746857

Answer (score -2):

Just add the `timestamp` format to the mapping:

```
"timestamp": {
    "type": "date",
    "format": "epoch_millis"
}
```